# Using screws to install a set of french doors?

Tags: installation, doors

I am installing a set of french doors. I have installed many doors before, but I was curious as to whether or not anyone has tried using countersunk screws to install the door? If I needed to adjust the frame, I could just back out our put in each individual screw until it is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've installed four or five doors, and I exclusively use screws. And had to do exactly what you mention: Needed an adjustment and pulled it out.

Just make sure you're pre-drilling, especially through shims.

Edit: To avoid seeing the screw holes after, one trick is to put the screws underneath the stop trim. Steel exterior doors usually have a fabric/rubber magnetic strip attached to the stop trim, which ensures a full seal with the door. The screws go under this. Interior doors often requires you to attach the stop trim yourself, giving you ample opportunity to put the screws in the right place.

Comment: Only downside I can think of would be filling over the screw. You'd need to sink the screw in enough so you can get a good amount of putty in to fill it, especially in a door that gets a lot of use: my fear is that with only a tiny amount of putty (if the screw is just barely below the surface) it will crack and come loose from the vibrations of the door shutting.

Comment: The trick is to put the screws underneath the stop trim. Steel exterior doors usually have a fabric/rubber magnetic strip attached to the stop trim, which ensures a full seal with the door. The screws go under this. Interior doors often requires you to attach the stop trim yourself, giving you ample opportunity to put the screws in the right place. I've updated my answer to reflect this, thanks!